# Scrollbar touch target

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing the modal in HTML, but the keyboard-only user cannot access all content within the modal.
The only note is scrollbar touch target should be 44px*44px.
I read this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width.
But I don't know how to make scrollbar touch target 44px.
Please let me know how can make the scrollbar touch target should be 44px.
[image]

Comment: What does 'scrollbar touch target' mean?

Comment: I mean the area possible touch target in the scrollbar. it is not scrollbar width. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar-width is not supported by most browsers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width#browser_compatibility ).

If you want to change the behaviour or layout, you'll have to implement your own with css and javascript. You could check this one https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar It emulates the MacOS behaviour and layout.